# how to set default way of opening *.java file in win11

Tags: windows-11, java, file-association

It seems that we can't set default way of opening *.java file in the latest Windows 11

In options of "opening files", I can't see "default" option. I have also tried to change regedit table according to this note, but I can't find the directory https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_34379040/article/details/114218801

Comment: `Settings -> Apps -> Default apps`. Then type `.java` in the text field under "Set a default for a file type or link type". Finally, click on "Choose a default" (will be replaced by an app name if there is already a default app) and choose the app you would like to associate with `*.java` files.

Comment: This is a general OS question, not specific to Java and thus not about programming.

Comment: You absolutely can. We will need more details in English to assist you

Comment: Java files are just text, and what tool do you intend using for that?